# HP Elitebook 840 G2 is always preferring "Microsoft" EFI folder

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I had quite some problems starting Ubuntu on my new/used HP Elitebook 840 G2. I installed a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Whatever I did the system would only boot into Windows. In the boot device selection menu (accessed by pressing the Esc key at startup) however there was an entry for Ubuntu which made it load grub. I disabled Secure Boot, copied all the files from `/boot/efi/ubuntu` into `/boot/efi/BOOT`, and deleted all the files there, but none of these things solved the problem. There was also a menu for the boot order but the "ubuntu" entry did not appear there.

Finally I renamed the "Microsoft" folder on the EFI partition. This made the system load grub directly (although the Windows entry is no longer working, bad luck Microsoft). Is it possible that the UEFI loader has a hard-coded setting which prefers hard-coded entries in folders named *Microsoft*? It seems pretty strange or is there another explanation for this behavior?

For the Windows entry in grub I can now edit the command every time using "e" on the Windows 10 entry and correcting the folder name of the .efi file. Is there a way to make this edit permanent? I looked into the settings (`/etc/default/grub`), but did not find settings there.

Comment: There are several different ways of accessing the Windows bootloader during boot depending on what is pre-installed along with Windows on that specific model laptop, so regarding the second paragraph it's impossible to generalize. However we don't give up. If there is a boot problem, it is possible to generate a detailed Boot Info Script by running the Boot-Repair program which includes recommendations about how to fix the problem.

Comment: We uses to use your "fix", but grub only boots working Windows, so if Windows turns fast start up back on or needs chkdsk, you cannot boot Windows at all. And a Windows update will overwrite the /EFI/Microsoft entry. And you do not copy all of /EFI/ubuntu into /EFI/Boot. In /EFI/Boot should be bootx64.efi, orginally a copy of Windows .efi file but grub should make it a copy of shimx64.efi. And that is a hard drive entry in UEFI.  Have you updated UEFI, many have said that helps? Sony, HP & others workarounds:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win